# Why does the data explorer have inaccessible columns?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, sql

Why does the data explorer have columns that do not return visible results? For example, the column Votes.UserId does not return any information. This makes sense to me. I just don't understand why the column exists in the first place.

Comment: They cleared the colomn, but didnt delete it when they sanitized the data set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> the column Votes.UserId does not return any information

That is not correct. While most content in that column is sanitized (because most voting is anonymous),

```
select distinct VoteTypeId from Votes where UserId is not null
```

gives you two results: 5 (`Favorite`) and 8 (`BountyStart`), because these kinds of votes are *not* anonymous. I don't actually know why we don't also leave 1 (`AcceptedByOriginator`) intact; after all it's not secret (and easily found out) who the voter in that case is.

But either way: The `Vote.UserId` column is not empty.